# Printing GroupBox directly from label printer

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I have to create a label with a code39 barcode and some information text.
I create the label inside a GroupBox, which works perfectly fine. After the label creation is done, I have to print this GroupBox (or at least the controls inside) with a label printer (Meto SP40 II).

To print the GroupBox, I draw it to a bitmap and save the bitmap as jpg and print the jpg. When I print the jpg with a "normal" printer, the quality is fine and I can scan the bar-code without a problem. But when I print the jpg with the label printer, the quality is really bad and i can't scan the bar-code. This is the code I use to create and print the jpg.

```
public void PrintBarcodeGrpb()
{
     Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(groupBox1.Width, groupBox1.Height);
     groupBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp,groupBox1.ClientRectangle);
     bmp.Save(barcodeSavePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

     PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
     doc.PrintPage += Doc_PrintPage;
     doc.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Etiketten", 75, 40);
     doc.Print();
     doc.Dispose();

}

private void Doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{

     Image img = Image.FromFile(barcodeSavePath);
     Point loc = new Point(0,0);
     e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);

}
```

I guess the quality problem occurs because the printer has a problem with the jpg. But even when I print the bitmap directly without saving it as jpg, the quality is the same. Is there a way to print the GroupBox without drawing it to a bitmap?

**EDIT**

When I create and print the label this way:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(BarcodeLocation, textFont, Brushes.Black, 33,29);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(BarcodeText, barcodeFont, Brushes.Black, 15, 58);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(BarcodeText, textFont, Brushes.Black, 35, 97);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(lblKST.Text, textFont, Brushes.Black, 233, 29);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(lblKTR.Text, textFont, Brushes.Black, 233, 97);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(CostCentre, textFont, Brushes.Black, 233, 120);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(CostTypes, textFont, Brushes.Black, 33, 120);
```

the quality of the printed label is fine. It's a lot of testing and printing before everything is on the right place, but for me it was a lot easier then trying to print the whole GroupBox.

Comment: Is this an issue with the image or the label printer settings?

Comment: I think its an issue with the image, because i can print other label with the same printer settings without a problem

Comment: And the quality problem is low resolution? Perhaps an image of the quality issues? I suspect a wrong DPI/low resolution, but perhaps it's a different problem?

Comment: I tried to get a better quality with an encoder (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoderparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) but the resolution is always the same

Comment: Set the Bitmap Dpi to 200 and save it as PNG (important).

Comment: I've set the Dpi to 200 (and higher) and saved it as PNG, but the quality of the printed label is the same.